# Is there a way to add a wiki in Magento?

Tags: module, magento-1.8

I was wondering if there was already a module or built-in way that I'm missing to add a wiki to a Magento site? I tried looking through modules, the Magento forums/wiki, and didn't find an answer. I was hoping to find something that would quickly be able to add a wiki such as how Magento has it on their own website.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/

I'd like to be able to have the way a wiki easy links things together but have it use the css/style settings I'm setting in the Magento back-end.

Thanks!

Comment: There is at least one extension with the word "wiki" init listed on http://packages.firegento.com: connect20/udc_wiki http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Udc_Wiki/0.1/Udc_Wiki-0.1.tgz

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, but it isn't meant for the end-users ("An internal wiki for your business policies and procedures"). I'm looking for a wiki that's visible to the end user (to provide information about products and configurations in wiki format).

Comment: packages.firegento.com lists all modules which were updated in the last 1.5(?) years? maybe two, maybe only one. But if there is no, there is at least no free module on connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you install a wiki in parallel to magento, maybe even on a different sub domain.

Because:
a public wiki is a very complex application, which handles user input in a lot of ways.
This means, a lot of things you could do wrong to get big security holes.
Alone from the possible userbase it is a better choice to take an existing wiki software, instead of someone who once put this into a module.

I think you initial intention is to have a wiki without having to manage separate user accounts. This would be possible by adding a specialized login to the wiki. But that would be another question.